# unique sequential ID in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

@contributorpw- When I use your code I get this error message in the screenshots...thank you for your collaboration and your precious time that you share with the community. I am a beginner in app scripting.

[message erreur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP4CY.png)

Comment: Please post [mcve]

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)